# Making smoothly animated striped div

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble making a smoothly animated striped div, like a progress bar.

CSS:

```
.animationStripes{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0) 25px, blue 25px, blue 50px);
  -webkit-animation:progress 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:progress 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:progress 2s linear infinite;
  animation:progress 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes progress{
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -70px 0px;
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4wPv1ogKNMfJ6rQPhZdJ?p=preview

The problem is that there is a weird misalignment on the very right side of the background image gradient. How do i fix this misalignment?

Comment: How about changing the `width` of the element to `283px`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I managed to fix it just by adding one thing and making no alterations to my original code. Simply adding `background-size: 150% 100%;` kept the image from clipping awkwardly on the right side.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4wPv1ogKNMfJ6rQPhZdJ?p=preview

Comment: MUCH easier than the other solutions I found online -- THANK YOU!

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/uniqlo-stripe-hovers/) on CSS Tricks?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans);
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
}

.product {
  width: 376px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.product>img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.product:hover .product-hover,
.product:active .product-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.product-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  animation: barberpole 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes barberpole {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 60px 30px;
  }
}

.product-info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  background: white;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px 10px 50px 10px;
}

.subhead {
  color: #f00;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.product-name {
  color: #990033;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.price {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.amount {
  color: red;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.amount>span {
  font-size: 75%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

VIEW SCSS CODE
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-hover"></div> <img src="http://fillmurray.com/300/300" />
  <div class="product-info">
    <div class="subhead">Sale</div>
    <h2 class="product-name">Fleece</h2>
    <p class="product-description">Beat the chill and get cozy.</p>
    <div class="price"> <span class="from">from</span> <span class="amount">        <span>$</span>9.90 </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the linear gradient with percentage values, not with pixel. apply background-size, in your case i'd say `background-size:50px 50px;` and in keyframes, move the background as much, as is the background size `background-position: -50px 0px;`

Also an example
http://plnkr.co/edit/HrSxkhYZaWp81fAQEaJn?p=preview

If the answer suits you, then mark it as answered and have a good day :)

Comment: Hmm. Well now when i use percentages i have a problem with there being jagged edges on the stripes, which is weird (looks same in your demo). I'm looking at this in chrome